# Get information from a node that has just been saved to update a different node

Tags: 7, nodes

I have 2 different content types "factory" and "measurement" that are related with an entity reference field. I am using a computed field to store the latest measurement as a field of the factory content type. The problem is that in order for the computed field to be "re-computed", the factory node that the measurement refers to, needs to be updated.

My first thought was to batch update all the factory nodes in predefined intervals. This has a very important downside: the factory information (and specifically the latest measurement that I'm interested in) will not be updated until the batch update is executed.

My next thought was that I could use a hook whenever a new measurement is created and update the corresponding (=the one that the entity reference points to) factory. The problem is that [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) will not give me the information that I want (i.e. the entity reference field that points to the factory) since in the hook's description it states clearly that:

> You should not rely on data in the database at this time as it is not
>   updated yet.

Is there any other way to execute a piece of code whenever a new node of specific type (i.e. measurement) is saved/created and **have the node's fields available** in my code? How do Rules do it?

P.S: I thought about using Rules but it seems like an overkill for such a simple thing to install a pretty heavy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `hook_node_insert($node)` you cannot reliably read saved node's data from database, but you can read data from `$node` object provided to that hook.